# Whats the mistake here?

Tags: php, html, facebook

It is probably a silly mistake but i'm into splits because of it :(

Language : PHP 5.4.7 \n Framework: CodeIgniter 2.1.3 , SDK: Facebook PHP SDK 3.2.2

Please consider the following Controller function:-

```
public function index()
{
  //  $this->__construct();
    $data['profile'] = $this->_facebook->api('/me?fields=id');
    $this->load->view('user_profile',$data);
}
```

And the corresponding view (user_profile.php) :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Showing the user profile</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//echo print_r($user_profile,TRUE);
echo '<IMG SRC="http://graph.facebook.com/'. $profile['id'] . '/picture" HEIGHT=32 WIDTH=32 /> ';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code shows the profile picture in Internet Explorer but in Chrome the page is blank. On viewing page source, it is blank.

Comment: Where is $profile['id'] being set?

Comment: in the `function index()` in controller. I've checked, the image url is getting generated correctly (checked in Internet Explorer where the code is working fine).

Comment: so $this->_facebook->api('/me?fields=id') is an array? It looks like it would return a string (the id) See my answer below.

Comment: yes it is an array. If I did `$this->facebook->getUser()` , it would return _id_ as string.

Comment: Could you post the source from IE? I can't reproduce the problem in Chrome. The HTML you provide above, with a valid user id inserted, works fine for me.

Comment: This could be a simple error like the api returning an object, not an array. It's possible that what you're seeing in IE is cached.

Comment: I get this code in IE `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Showing the user profile
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
            <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100000034935902/picture/type=normal" alt="profile Photo" />
  </body>

</html>`

Comment: May be i'll try some other browser (may be _safari_) and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with writing cleaner html.

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $profile['id']; ?>/picture" alt="Profile Photo" height="32" width="32" />
```

Don't capitalize tags and img requires an alt attribute. I always quote attribute values, even when they're numbers.

Comment: Thank you for showing a neater way of writing html. But still the problem is not resolved. In Chrome in _Canvas Frame_ there is no html code when viewing source, whereas in IE, html is as expected .